# Terminating a Java program without exit Matlab?

Tags: java, matlab, error-handling

So recently I have been working on a Java applet that will be executed from Matlab (Since matlab is an easy way to handle and parse large arrays). I have a problem in this context. In my Java program i usually handle exceptions and other mistakes by following:

```
System.err.println("WARNING: [SOME ERROR MESSEAGE GOES HERE]"); 
System.exit(-1);
```

What I seek is to receive the error message in Matlab and shutdown the Java applet.

The problem is that the `System.exit(-1)` statements terminate **both** Matlab and Java and hence brings me back to my desktop.

Do any of you have any recommendation on how to only shut down my Java applet and hereby remain Matlab  open so that the user receives the error message.

Comment: If I correctly understand you, run Matlab in different process.

Comment: I don't know how / whether this is feasible, but the only thing that comes to mind is to set up a communication channel between you Matlab and Java processes so that they can exchange much more informations than a return code. In a comment to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12473083/choice-of-ipc-method) ZeroMQ is suggested; as I don't know that library, I don't know if it can fit your requirements.

Comment: @ᴍarounᴍaroun I am not entirely sure how that would solve it - are you refering to the same as watery?

Comment: @watery It might be. However, I am unfamiliar with ZeroMQ and are looking for a quick and dirty way to terminate my java application without terminating the matlab script.

Comment: Did you already see [this](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/pdf_doc/matlab/apiext.pdf)? I just looked at the index, and from chapter 7 paragraph titles it seems that Java code becames part of the same Matlab instance (i.e. you're not invoking an external program, but a Java library as you would call a Matlab library), maybe that's the source of your problem. You then do not need to call `System.exit()` to close your Java program, but just end it returning from `main()`.

Comment: And as that's the level of integration between Java and Matlab there may be ways to send extensive error informations to Matlab from your Java code without any external tool / library.

Comment: @watery I think you are right! Well done! 
I believe a propper way to 'end' the java program would be to simply throw an exception in case any problem occur.

Comment: @SteewDK Please try it and if it works post the answer here for future reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Description:**
Thanks to @watery and the [MATLAB External Interfaces handbook](http://www.mathworks.com/help/pdf_doc/matlab/apiext.pdf) it appears that the Java code becomes a part of the MATLAB instance. Hence,  `System.exit(-1)` will not only terminate the JAVA program but also MATLAB itself.

**Solution:**
Do not use  `System.exit(-1)` if you plan on running java classes from matlab. Instead what you can do is throw an unchecked exception in JAVA (You can either use pre-defined exceptions or create exceptions your self as shown below).

**Example:**

```
if (problem)
    throw new InsufficientInputException("[ERROR MESSAGE GOES HERE]");
```

Where you need to create the unchecked Exception yourself and add `throws InsufficientInputException` to the method where the `if(problem)` is nested within.

```
public class InsufficientInputException extends Exception{
    public InsufficientInputException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}
```

This will terminate the JAVA program, leave the user (in MATLAB) with an error message, **but not terminate MATLAB.**

Comment: If this is the right solution, you should mark it as an answer, like @DennisJaheruddin suggested.